# Python append to specific column in data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, append

I have a data frame df with 3 columns and a loop creating strings from a text file depending on the column-names of the loop:

```
exampletext = "Nr1 thisword1 and Nr2 thisword2 and Nr3 thisword3"
Columnnames = ("Nr1", "Nr2", "Nr3")
df1= pd.DataFrame(columns = Columnnames)
for i in range(0,len(Columnnames)):
   solution = exampletext.find(Columnnames[i])
   lsolution= len(Columnnames[i])
   Solutionwords = exampletext[solution+lsolution:solution+lsolution+10]
```

Now I want to append the solutionwords at the end of the dataframe df1 in the correct field, e.g. when looking for Nr1 I want to append the solutionwords to column named Nr1. 
I tried working with append and creating a list, but this will just append at the end of the list. I need the data frame to seperate the words depending on the word I was looking for. Thank you for any help!

edit for desired output and readability:
Desired Output should be a data frame and look like the following:

Nr1       | Nr2       | Nr3

thisword1 | thisword2 | thisword3

Comment: Can you add the desired output for your exampletext pls?

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that your word for the cell value always follows your column name and is separated by a space. In which case, I'd probably try and achieve this by adding your values to a dictionary and then creating a dataframe from it after it contains the data you want, like this:

```
example_text = "Nr1 thisword1 and Nr2 thisword2 and Nr3 thisword3"
column_names = ("Nr1", "Nr2", "Nr3")

d = dict()
split_text = example_text.split(' ')
for i, text in enumerate(split_text):
    if text in column_names:
        d[text] = split_text[i+1]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

which will give you:

```
>>> df 
         Nr1        Nr2        Nr3
0  thisword1  thisword2  thisword3
```